# Having trouble setting Ember objects to both contain references to each other

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

### Answered

I've solved the problem, it has to do with my adapter, and I'll post more in an answer,
but here's a link to a problem I'm having with the fix [Ember get not getting certain attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456890/ember-get-not-getting-certain-attribute)

### Original Question

I have the following code:

```
customerSignUp: function () {
    var customer = this.get('store').createRecord('customer', {
        description: 'Why hello sir'
    });
    var model = this.get('model');
    model.set('customer', customer);
    customer.save().then(function() {
        model.save().then(function() {
            customer.set('user', model);
            customer.save();
        });
    });
}
```

With the following backing models:

```
App.User = App.Person.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'), // Actually their primary email.
    customer: DS.belongsTo('customer', {async: true })
});

App.Customer = DS.Model.extend({
    user: DS.belongsTo('user', {async: true}),
    description: DS.attr('string')
});
```

(App.Person just passes along some naming conventions)

The `customerSignUp` function is trying to get *both* objects to refer to the other, so that either one could get attributes from the other as needed (the `user` model is planned to have more relationships like this in the future, so that one user can have multiple "roles" on the site).

The problem is that I can't get both to stably refer to each other. With this current implementation the model (user) points to the customer just fine, but the customer for some reason simply has it's user field set to `<computed>` in the Ember Debugger, and the record saved in the database doesn't even have a `user` field. It seems to me like **some** of my saves are overwriting the values or changing the underlying objects so they're no longer true? Honestly I'm just confused.

I've tried all kinds of different orderings of the `save`s and `set`s, but so far only one at a time works, or if both work, it's because I haven't saved one of them to the database. Any advice? Is this even necessary? Will the `customer` object have access to it's `user` even if there isn't an id explicitly stored in the `customer`?

Could this have to do with the [adapter I'm using](https://github.com/roundscope/ember-couchdb-kit)?

### Update

With this implementation of `customerSignUp`:

```
customerSignUp: function () {
    var model = this.get('model');
    var customer = this.get('store').createRecord('customer', {
        description: 'Why hello sir',
        user: model
    });
    customer.save().then(function() {
    model.set('customer', customer);
        model.save();
    });
}
```

The `customer` relationship on the `user` is set **for a moment**, but then resets to null. The `user` relationship is just `<computed>` and I don't think was ever set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had to do with my adapter.

This function:

```
serializeBelongsTo: function(record, json, relationship) {
      console.log("serializeBelongsTo");
      var attribute, belongsTo, key;
      attribute = relationship.options.attribute || "id";
      console.log(attribute);
      key = relationship.key;
      console.log(key);
      belongsTo = Ember.get(record, key);
      console.log(belongsTo);
      if (Ember.isNone(belongsTo)) {
        return;
      }
      var content = belongsTo.content;
      console.log(content);
      var temp = Ember.get(belongsTo, attribute);
      console.log(temp);
      json[key] = temp;
      console.log(json);
      if (relationship.options.polymorphic) {
        return json[key + "_type"] = belongsTo.constructor.typeKey;
      }
      else {
        return json;
      }
```

returns a value of `undefined` from `Ember.get(belongsTo, attribute)` even though `belongsTo` and `attribute` are correctly set, although `belongsTo` has it's data buried in a `content` object, which this [SO post details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456890/ember-get-not-getting-certain-attribute).