# Ember get not getting certain attribute

Tags: javascript, ember.js, couchdb, ember-data

When running the following from the `UserController` on Google Chrome, with `ember-couchdb-kit-0.9`, Ember Data `v1.0.0-beta.3-56-g8367aa5`, Ember `v1.0.0`, and [this couchdb adapter](https://github.com/roundscope/ember-couchdb-kit):

```
customerSignUp: function () {
            var model = this.get('model');
            var customer = this.get('store').createRecord('customer', {
                description: 'Why hello sir',
                user: model
            });
            customer.save().then(function() {
                model.set('customer', customer);
                model.save();
            });
        }
```

with these models:

```
App.User = App.Person.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    customer: DS.belongsTo('customer', {async: true })

App.Customer = DS.Model.extend({
    user: DS.belongsTo('user', {async: true}),
    description: DS.attr('string')
});
```

neither the user nor the customer has their relationship set properly (in the Ember Debugger the user has `null` and the customer has `<computed>`, rather than some sort of `<EmberPromiseObject>` which is what they have when it works).
This only happens when the object in question is persisted. If the `save()` calls are omitted, both have correctly set relationships, but of course the database hasn't been updated with this information. Whenever the saves happen, the relationships are overwritten with empty entries.

I found that the problem was in the adapter's `serializeBelongsTo` function, which I've now changed my copy to the following:

```
serializeBelongsTo: function(record, json, relationship) {
      console.log("serializeBelongsTo");
      console.log(record.get('user'));
      console.log(json);
      console.log(relationship);
      var attribute, belongsTo, key;
      attribute = relationship.options.attribute || "id";
      console.log(attribute);
      key = relationship.key;
      console.log(key);
      belongsTo = Ember.get(record, key);
      console.log(belongsTo);
      if (Ember.isNone(belongsTo)) {
        return;
      }
      json[key] = Ember.get(belongsTo, attribute);
      console.log(Ember.get(belongsTo, attribute));
      console.log(json);
      if (relationship.options.polymorphic) {
        return json[key + "_type"] = belongsTo.constructor.typeKey;
      }
      else {
        return json;
      }
    }
```

`attribute`, `belongsTo`, and `key` all log as correct, but
`console.log(Ember.get(belongsTo, attribute));` returns `undefined`,
which I've tried to change to 
`console.log(Ember.get(Ember.get(belongsTo, 'content'), attribute));` 
since `console.log(belongsTo);` told me the `id` attribute was hidden inside a `content` object. Attached is a screenshot showing what I mean.
[image: screenshot from 2013-12-07 18 15 52]
The change doesn't fix the problem though, and I keep getting `undefined`. No matter what method I use to try to get the id out of the `belongsTo` object, I always get either `null` or `undefined`. Here are some examples of things I've tried to get `content` out of the object:

```
var content = belongsTo.content;
var content = Ember.get(belongsTo, 'content');
var content = belongsTo.get('content');
```

`console.log(json);` returns `Object {description: "Why hello sir", user: undefined}`

Here's a pastebin showing relevant output: http://pastebin.com/v4mb3PJ2

### Update

A very confusing update!

When I save the model from a different function:

```
saveModel: function() {
    this.get('model').save().then(
        function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
            console.log('Saved successfully.');
        },
        function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(errorThrown);
            console.log(textStatus);
        }
    );
}
```

The model is correctly saved. Everything in `serializeBelongsto` works exactly as expected.

Here's a different pastebin showing output for this case: http://pastebin.com/Vawur8Q0

Comment: I'm beginning to think this is a synchronization issue. The promises aren't resolving in time for the function, but they are resolving in time for my console outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. Basically the `belongsTo` object in `serializeBelongsTo` wasn't really resolved by the time it was being referenced, which I found out by querying `isFulfilled`. So I implemented by saving side this way:

```
function saveOn (target, attribute) {
    target.addObserver(attribute, function () {
        if (target.get(attribute)) {
            console.log("Inside with %@".fmt(attribute));
            target.removeObserver(attribute);
            Ember.run.once(target, function() {
                target.save();
            });
        }
    });
};

customerSignUp: function () {
    var model = this.get('model');
    var customer = this.get('store').createRecord('customer', {
        description: 'Why hello sir'
    });
    customer.save().then(function () {
        model.set('customer', customer);
        customer.set('user', model);
        saveOn(customer, 'user.isFulfilled');
        saveOn(model, 'customer.isFulfilled');
    });
}
```

Now everything works like a charm. It might be a good idea for `serializeBelongsTo` to take this into account though. This line: `console.log(Ember.get(belongsTo, 'isFulfilled'));` was coming up `false` in my case. There was just a race condition of some sort between the creation of the record and it's serialization!

I'd like to make my `saveOn` function return a promise though, which I could then use to chain multiple `saveOn`s together. That way I wouldn't have to do a `customer.save()` to make sure the id's were populated.