# Make Ember function return a promise from callback

Tags: javascript, ember.js, promise

I want to have a function return the promise from `model.save()`, but the call to `model.save()` is in a callback, and so doesn't make it up the chain. Here's what I mean:

```
function saveOn (target, attribute) {
    target.addObserver(attribute, function () {
        if (target.get(attribute)) {
            target.removeObserver(attribute);
            Ember.run.once(target, function() {
                target.save();
            });
        }
    });
};
```

(this function was necessary to solve [this problem I previously posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456890/ember-get-not-getting-certain-attribute/20483604#20483604))

I want the `target.save();` line to instead be: `return target.save();`

Then I could do this:

```
saveOn().then();
```

which as it stands doesn't work, the error message simply being that `then` doesn't exist on that object.

### Update

```
teacherSignUp: function() {
    var model = this.get('model');
    var teacher = this.get('store').createRecord('teacher', {
        description: 'Why hello sir',
        user: model
    });
    model.set('teacher', teacher);
    saveOn(teacher, 'user.isFulfilled').then(function() {
        console.log("Model");
        saveOn(model, 'teacher.isFulfilled');
    });
}
```

The `console.log("Model");` is successfully called, but the model is never persisted at all.
What's happening here?

### Update Solved

It the second observer on the model was never firing, since after the teacher had completed `saveOn` the model was already done. I just changed the `saveOn(model, 'teacher.isFulfilled');` to `model.save();` and it works great.

Comment: I thought for a moment that the `Ember.run.once` was interfering with the second call, but I removed it and it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass another parameter.

```
function saveOn (target, attribute, then) {
    target.addObserver(attribute, function () {
        if (target.get(attribute)) {
            target.removeObserver(attribute);
            Ember.run.once(target, function() {
                var promise = target.save();
                if(then){ 
                  promise.then(function(){ then(); });
          });
        }
    });
};
```

or create another promise and resolve in the then

```
function saveOn (target, attribute) {
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){

      target.addObserver(attribute, function () {
        if (target.get(attribute)) {
            target.removeObserver(attribute);
            Ember.run.once(target, function() {
                target.save().then(function(record){ resolve(record); },
                      function(error){ reject(error); });
          });
        }
      });
    });
};
```

teacher.isFulfilled is probably already changed, so the observer isn't firing, cause it isn't changing, try checking before creating the observer and skipping that portion if already true/exists etc.

Comment: Second one worked exactly as I hoped. Thanks for making the Promise API clear!

Comment: Actually nevermind.. I'm editing my new issue with the second one into my original question.

Comment: Never mind again! Your implementation was great, but since it worked it changed the assumptions I was making. Thanks again for your help!